# Solr query starts with

Tags: solr

How I write a query in Solr that performs "start with" function? For example, if I have 3 documents with the following title fields:

1. "Star Wars Episode I"
2. "Star Wars Episode II"
3. "Star Trek"
4. "My Star Wars movie"

I want the query to return first 2 documents, whose title starts with "Star Wars"

**Edit**: For the record, this is what I end up using:

```
fq=(name:"/Apple Ipad.*/")&wt=xml
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define **'^'** as the first character of a search phrase meaning "Starts With".

Define **'$'** as the last character of a search phrase meaning "Ends With".

Pre-parse your search phrase, substituting '^' and '$' appropriately.

You can use regular expressions

https://web.archive.org/web/20161030170947/http://www.openjems.com/solr-regex-tutorial/

Comment: From the link referenced in the answer: "Notice that unlike Perl, there is no anchoring syntax (^ and $) in Solr. Instead, all Solr regexes are anchored in the beginning with a ^ and in the end with a $ by default. If you do not want your searches to be anchored, then you need to specify .* on both sides of your regex."